# Get value from a JSON with PHP

Tags: php, json

How can I get the value of `name` in `infos` ?

```
{
    "infos": {
        "name": "Marc Twain"
    },
    "datas": [
        {...}
    ]
}
```

Do I really need a `foreach` ?

What I tried without a success:

```
$json = json_decode($file);
$json->infos[0]->name
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`infos` is not an array, so you would simply do:

```
$json->infos->name
```

Answer (score 3):

OK: you are almost right!

```
$json = json_decode($file, true);
```

You can access the various elements as in any *standard* array:

```
echo $json['infos']['name'];
```

Explanation:
`json_decode` has got an optional parameter, `bool $assoc = false` by default. By calling the function setting it to `true`, we are telling PHP to return an associative array (a.k.a. "searchable" in the usual indexes way), instead of an object!

Comment: Stange, it do not echo me anything. $file echoes the right file.

Comment: Would you mind giving a little bit more precise json tree? Just to understand your structure!

Comment: It seems your json is somehow malformed, I'm trying to figure out which the problem is but right now no good news! There is a syntax error somewhere in the code